# How can I expose a StatefulSet service with ClusterIP None on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-statefulset

How can I expose a StatefulSet service (cassandra, mysql, etc...) with `ClusterIP=None` on Kubernetes in Google Cloud Platform?

I need to change the ClusterIP config? Or I need to configure Google Cloud NAT? Or I need to change other things?

Thanks

EDIT: I want to connect to cassandra from an external IP, from anyplace on the internet

EDIT2: I guess that the solution is to use `LoadBalance` instead of `ClusterIP`, but when I use `LoadBalance`, the Cassandra nodes can't find the seed node. Then I sill using `ClusterIP=None` to Cassandra cluster, and I created another POD with `type=LoadBalance` to connect to Cassandra and to have connections to exterior. And now it's working :)

Comment: Why do you want the ClusterIP to be None?

Comment: @FrankYuchengGu service for statefulset would have ClusterIP=None & it is called Headless Service

Comment: @Rui, do you mean exposing outside the cluster?

Comment: You might want to take a look at following articles that gives you some idea on what you want to achieve . https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services and https://itnext.io/exposing-statefulsets-in-kubernetes-698730fb92a1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ClusterIP services are not exposed outside of the Kubernetes cluster. Perhaps you mean to use a NodePort or LoadBalancer service instead?

Answer (score 5):

If by "***expose***" you mean ability to reach your service endpoints without cluster IP , then just use `selector` in your headless service, i.e.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: cassandra
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: cassandra
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
```

For more details refer to  [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#with-selectors)

Otherwise, if you want to expose your deployments outside of the cluster, you won't be able to do it with headless service.

Comment: I want to expose to the internet.
I want that external servers connect to cassandra.

Comment: @RuiMartins then what is the reason behind **ClusterIP: None** ?  Why can't expose with port type **LoadBalancer**?

Comment: I followed the steps of the examples of "HOW TO CREATE A CASSANDRA CLUSTER ON KUBERNETES"

Comment: I changed to "LoadBalancer", but with "LoadBalancer" only one node is started, the other nodes fails. I think that cassandra needs to be ClusterIP without IP. I read this here: https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger-kubernetes/issues/33 
"this could have been caused by me changing the clusterIP setting to get an ip, instead of leaving it as None. per the docs - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/ - a headless service is required, so this looks like PEBKAC. works fine now."

Comment: Initially, you wanted to expose your service to the internet and now returning to the statement that headless service is required. This is something controversial.  The only possible solution is to expose headless service via ingress with `matchLabels` selector

Answer (score 1):

If you want to expose the service externally, you will need a service that is ClusterIP backed whether that be a NodePort or LoadBalancer; even if you use ingress, you will need to back it up with a ClusterIP service at the very least.

The ClusterIP is only internal and provides the Kubebernetes cluster a fixed endpoint to reference your deployment/pod **internally**. The simplest method to expose your services is to use a `NodePort`, in which case your service will take on the IP of the node externally with a high port number (30000+). On GCP, if you define a `load-balancer`, you will be given an external IP, and the traffic will be forwarded in order to your pods in the stateful sets. If you use an ingress, your external IP will be that of your ingress, and the packet forwarding to your services will be done based on the request URL (ie. you can have multiple FQDNs mapped to a single external IP in your DNS).

"Headless" services are mainly used to decouple your design from Kubernetes. The assumption is that you will be doing your own service discovery, and I don't believe that is a good use case for your application.

Hope this helps!